# Do frontpage questions learn from user preferences?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, homepage

I just realized that my Stack Overflow frontpage is filled with Android & other *Favorite Tags*. I tried to look it up from Chrome's incognito mode and it's quite different than when I'm logged in.

Are frontpage questions really different for logged in and non logged in users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does -- see here for details:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

On top of that, we auto-infer favorite tags based on browsing preferences if we reach statistically significant thresholds for a user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The interesting tab changes a lot well because it is interesting :)

Comment: It depends on the site. SO does implement this - other sites don't.