# Why doesn't my question show up on the frontpage?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, homepage

I just asked a question on Stack Overflow. Often I notice my questions coming through on the front-page, but this one isn't there, even after I gave it some time. Why is this?

Comment: It may have disappeared from the front page already. Things can go pretty fast on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I admit this is weird because it was asked 10 minutes ago and does not show up on the front page. Right now, the front page displays post with a last activity going up to an hours or so. It should show up unless you have a lot of downvotes which is not the case.

Comment: The homepage is going to be different for each user, and has a complex formula to determine what each person sees.  It's *possible* for a new question to not be on it at all, or not for very long, but it's also possible that other users will have seen it based on their activities.

Comment: @Servy *The more you know...*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the front page contains *interesting* questions, not the [newest questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). Many new questions don't show up on the front page.

> [image]

You do show up in the newest list (see below), but yours isn't one of the questions that appeared on the front page for me. Apparently front page questions [vary from user to user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83078/152515), so others would have seen it there.

> [image: screenshot of the question in the newest list]

Comment: "Because the front page contains *interesting* questions" harsh

Comment: @RichardTingle Hey now. My mother growing up would always say my food was *interesting* in the worst of ways.

Comment: In this context *interesting questions* is questions that are likely to be of interest to an individual user based on the tags and whatever other formula StackOverflow applies. Many users would find questions on Java or C# extremely interesting, whereas others would have no interest whatsoever as these technologies are not ones used by them. To say a question is not interesting to a specific user, does not mean it is not in general interesting, or of interest to specific others. I don't see this as a harsh statement in the context provided, albeit it could have been worded better to show that.